# python tkinter not updating json file

Tags: python, json, tkinter

Im learning how to update, write and read `json` files in python.

When I update my `json` file with exception handling it gives an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py",
line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)   File "/Users/montekkundan/Downloads/coding/python/password-manager/main.py",
line 53, in save
    data = json.load(data_file)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py",
line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py",
line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py",
line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py",
line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**python function:**

```
def save():
    website = website_entry.get()
    email = email_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()
    new_data = {
        website: {
            "email": email,
            "password": password,
        }
    }

    if len(website) == 0 or len(password) == 0:
        messagebox.showerror(title="Oops!", message="Please make sure you haven't left any fields empty.")

    else:
        
        try:
            with open("data.json", "r") as data_file:
                # Reading old data
                data = json.load(data_file)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            with open("data.json", "w") as data_file:
                json.dump(new_data, data_file, indent=4)
        else:
            # Updating old data with new data
            data.update(new_data)

            with open("data.json", "w") as data_file:
                # Saving updated data
                json.dump(data, data_file, indent=4)
        finally:
            website_entry.delete(0, END)
            password_entry.delete(0, END)
```

Comment: could you please explain more, i don't get it how to clear this error.

Comment: Could you please tell how to do that, i don't get what to change.

Comment: first check what you have in file. It seems it is empty. And empty file is uncorrect JSON and it raise error. You can read JSON only if it has some data. And when it is empty then you should skip it and create empty directory `data = dict()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what you have in file - it seems it is empty.
And empty file/string is uncorrect JSON and it raises error.

You should rather create new empty dict `data` when it can't find file or it has problem to read it.

```
try:
    with open("data.json", "r") as data_file:
        # Reading old data
        data = json.load(data_file)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Problem: FileNotFoundError")
    data = dict()
except json.JSONDecodeError:
    print("Problem: JSONDecodeError")
    data = dict()

finally:
    
    # --- always ---
    
    data.update(new_data)
    
    with open("data.json", "w") as data_file:
        # Saving updated data
        json.dump(data, data_file, indent=4)
    
    website_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)
```